# New fragment to overlap toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a use case where I download some data from the network and I populate a list and when user clicks on of them then there's another list ( again with data from the network ). When user clicks an item on this second list I want to display a new screen.

What I have done so far is an Activity with two fragments (one for each list). Both of these fragments are inside a `CoordinatorLayout` and below a Toolbar. But the new screen I want to display should'nt contain a Toolbar. Therefore I can't use the `FrameLayout` I used for the other two fragments. 
And because I want the user when starts this new screen to be able with the back button move back to the previous state ( 2nd list loaded and scrolled until user clicked an item ) I don't think its possible to create a new `Activity` since it isn't easy to keep the state.

Is there a way I can create a new Fragment above the previous **and** the `Toolbar` and if I just create this fragment wouldn't there be any performance cost since OS will have to draw two fragments at the same time (but only one displayed) ? Note that there are a lot of images loaded already in the second fragment.

My xml layout right now looks like this :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/dl_container"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/tb_toolbar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/white" android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" android:textColor="@color/toolbat_title_color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_content" android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_video" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nv_navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_gravity="start"
    />
```

Comment: ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getActionBar().hide(); in your fragment onCreateView method

Comment: @Mes, Add white color background in previous fragment xml background

Answer (score 0):

to add your fragment in back stack (overlap),

```
 Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment,"")
            .addToBackStack("").commit();
```

for dont allow your fragment in backstack.

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment,"").commit();
```

Comment: I know that I can overlap this way but then Toolbar will be visible and I don't want it

Answer (score 0):

you need to hide the toolbar in fragment.

put

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

inside `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` of the fragment and it will hide the toolbar in fragment.

and to show the `toolbar` again when you leave the fragment you can call

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView (){
    super.onDestroyView();
ActionBar actionBar = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getActionBar();
actionBar.show();


}
```

Hope it hepls